# When was I born ? What is my name?

Tags: riddle

> HeY ! HeY ! I Am SUCH A gReAt PErSON ! WHeN WAs I BORn ?
>   AlSO, WHAt IS mY NAmE, sTaCK USEr ?

Comment: So tempted to answer Spongebob Squarepants. ;)

Comment: I could have sworn this was a Baconian cipher - but apparently not

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The answer is

> [Dimiti Ivanovich Mendeleev](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dmitri_Mendeleev).

The reason:

> If you ignore all spaces but very much mind the case, the riddle is a concatenation of symbols for chemical elements: for example, "A gReAt" gives you silver (Ag), Rhenium (Re) and Astatine (At). If you sum all the atomic numbers of said elements, you get 1834, which is the birth year of Mendeleev. With the chemical content of the riddle, there is few room for doubt that he's the solution (although it's probable he was not the only Human born that year).

Great riddle!

Comment: First I thought that this was a silly riddle with bad punctuation, now I can see how brilliant it is. Great work indeed.

Comment: Thank you and well done, the answer is indeed correct :)

Comment: Also, I thought Aristotle was more of a classical elements guy (your know, fire, air, water, earth, aether), quite ironic isn't it ?